# Conjugate prior of the Dirichlet distribution?

Tags: st.statistics, pr.probability

What is the [conjugate prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) distribution of the Dirichlet distribution?

---

Edit: Since I asked this question many years ago, I've written a [Python library](https://github.com/NeilGirdhar/efax) for working with exponential families.  [Maximum likelihood estimation of the Dirichlet distribution](https://github.com/NeilGirdhar/efax/blob/main/examples/maximum_likelihood_estimation.py) can be done using its expectation paramtrization (which is intimately related to the conjugate prior).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution

Comment: ...does not list the conjugate prior.

Comment: There is some discussion here: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/archives/2009/04/conjugate_prior.html

Comment: This might be better. http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0603120

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Neil](https://mathoverflow.net/users/634/neil) sent me an email asking:

===

I read your post at http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/archives/2009/04/conjugate_prior.html and I was wondering if you could expand on how to update the Dirichlet conjugate prior that you provided in your [paper](http://cvsp.cs.ntua.gr/publications/jpubl+bchap/LefkimmiatisMaragosPapandreou_BayesianMultiscalePoissonIntensityEstimation_ieee-j-ip09.pdf):

S. Lefkimmiatis, P. Maragos, and G. Papandreou,
Bayesian Inference on Multiscale Models for Poisson Intensity Estimation: Applications to Photon-Limited Image Denoising,
IEEE Transactions on Image Processing, vol. 18, no. 8, pp. 1724-1741, Aug. 2009

In other words, given in your paper's notation the prior hyper-parameters (vector $\mathbf{v}$, and scalar $\eta$), and $N$ Dirichlet observations (vectors $\mathbf{\theta}_n, n=1,\dots,N$), how do you update $\mathbf{v}$ and $\eta$?

===

Here is my response:

Conjugate pairs are so convenient because there is a standard and simple way to incorporate new data by just modifying the parameters of the prior density. One just multiplies the likelihood with its conjugate prior; the result has the same parametric form as the prior, and the new parameters can be readily "read-off" by comparing the likelihood-prior product with the prior parametric form. This is described in detail in all standard texts in Bayesian statistics such as Gelman et al. (2003) or Bernardo and Smith (2000).

In the case of the Dirichlet and its conjugate prior described in our paper and using its notation, after observing $N$ Dirichlet vectors $\mathbf{\theta}_n$, $n=1,\dots,N$, where each vector $\mathbf{\theta}_n$ is $D$ dimensional with elements $\theta_n[t]$, $t=1,\dots,D$, the $D+1$ hyper-parameters should be updated as follows:

- $\eta_N = \eta_0 + N$
- $v_N[t] = v_0[t] - \sum_{n=1}^N \ln \theta_n[t], \quad t=1,\dots,D$, where $\eta_0$,  $\mathbf{v}_0$ and $\eta_N$, $\mathbf{v}_N$ are the initial and updated model parameters, respectively.

You can verify this in a few lines of equations by following the previously described general rule.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!

Am I right that "theta" represents categorical parameter vector observations (i.e., their components are in [0,1])?

If the observations are "alpha", the parameter vectors of Dirichlet observations, then the update of v needs to be:

v_N[j] = v_0[j] + sum_n [  digamma(sum_i alpha_n[i]) - digamma(alpha_n[j]) ]

because that's the expected log of each component value, right?

Thanks again.  This was very helpful.

Comment: Hi,

at Level-1 we have $p(\mathbf{\theta}|\mathbf{\alpha}$, where 
$\theta$ is the Dirichlet observation lying on the $D$-dimensional simplex (components between 0 and 1 whose sum is 1), and $\mathbf{\alpha}$ is the Dirichlet distribution parameter vector.

At Level-2 we have the conj. prior $p(\mathbf{\alpha}|\eta,\mathbf{v})$ of our paper. 

In this setup, one observes $\theta$ vectors and updates the hyperparameters $\eta,\mathbf{v}$ that describe the density of $\mathbf{\alpha}$, which itself is considered hidden (it thus makes no sense to measure it).

Hope it is clearer now!
George

Comment: So to actually answer the question, is the Dirichlet distribution its own conjugate prior?

Comment: For others looking for the conjugate prior and it's derivation, it's in Appendix C at the end of the paper. @isarandi: no, it's quite different to a Dirichlet.

Comment: @George_Papandreou Thanks for sharing your work here (: That appendix is quite short - perhaps it'd be good to add it here also.

Comment: Though the books on bayesian statistics are no doubt a better source, Wikipedia has a useful article on [<conjugate priors for exponential family distributions>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Bayesian_estimation:_conjugate_distributions) (such as the Dirichlet).

Comment: @GeorgePapandreou: there is a typo in the reply. The actualisation should be$$v_N[t] = v_0[t] + \sum_{n=1}^N \ln \theta_n[t]$$not$$v_N[t] = v_0[t] - \sum_{n=1}^N \ln \theta_n[t]$$This confused a [reader on Cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/183383/7224).

Comment: @George_Papandreou, Thank you for your answer and your derivation in Appendix C, which is neat! My question is how does one sample $\mathbf{\alpha}$ from $p(\mathbf{\alpha}\mid \mathbf{\nu}, \eta) \propto \frac{1}{B(\mathbf{\alpha})^\eta}e^{-\sum_{t=1}^D \nu_t,\alpha_t}$ ? I am not sure if I can use rejection sampling while sampling a vector. Looking forward to your help. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Xi'an, I think it's actually just a difference in sign conventions. In the version of the paper that I can find (https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/188707037.pdf), the product $v_t \alpha_t$ appears with a minus sign in the exponential (see eq. (45)), whereas in the derivation on Cross Validated the minus sign is missing. FWIW, I prefer the convention in George's answer since it leads to positive $v_t$'s.

Comment: why is this answer so long? Why isn't it as follows. The conjugate prior of the Dirichellet is X. Saying what X says. Everything else is nice but makes it harder to extract the information people usually want to look up.